# Exit a double perform

Tags: cobol

Is-it possible to exit a double perform:

```
                PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>10
                    PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL K>3
                      IF J=2 and K=2
                         EXIT PERFORM
                      ELSE
                         display "LABEL A ===> PROCEDURE NOM_PROC2 "
                                 "J=/"J"/ AND K=/"K"/"
                      END-IF
                    END-PERFORM
                 END-PERFORM
```

I tried with EXITI PERFORM but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just bang in a `GO TO`. Anyone who wants to do such a thing will be happy with that. Remember the `EXIT PERFORM` is just a GO TO, only worse, as it has no label. What are you trying to do with your questions? Write COBOL like some other language? Which?

Comment: I think you need to show the real code you are attempting to replicate. That is presumably a made-up example, as @cshneid has shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
DisplayLabel section.
           PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>10
                PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL K>3
                  IF J=2 and K=2
                     EXIT SECTION
                  ELSE
                     display "LABEL A ===> PROCEDURE NOM_PROC2 "
                             "J=/"J"/ AND K=/"K"/"
                  END-IF
                END-PERFORM
             END-PERFORM
exit section.
```

Call the DisplayLabel section with "perform DisplayLabel"

Comment: Well, it would work. Also `EXIT PARAGRAPH`. I'd really hate to see that in a program. Next we need an `ALTER ... TO PROCEED TO ...` answer.

Comment: @Marcus Sundberg
the problem is that these double performs are already in a section

Comment: @MohamedELKHALIFI if that is your only problem with the idea, put them in a new SECTION.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to exit *both* in-line `PERFORMs` with the `EXIT PERFORM`.  The following technique should work.

```
01  SWITCHES.
    05  EOL-SW  PIC X VALUE 'N'.
        88  EOL       VALUE 'Y'.
        88  NOT-EOL   VALUE 'N'.

SET NOT-EOL TO TRUE
PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>10 OR EOL
    PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL K>3 OR EOL
        IF J=2 and K=2
            SET EOL TO TRUE
        ELSE
            display "LABEL A ===> PROCEDURE NOM_PROC2 "
                  "J=/"J"/ AND K=/"K"/"
        END-IF
    END-PERFORM
END-PERFORM
```

From a previous question you indicated you were transliterating PL/I to COBOL.  Just as with spoken and written languages, computer languages have idioms and colloquialisms that don't translate well.

I believe that, logically, this is equivalent.

```
PERFORM VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>2
    PERFORM VARYING K FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL K>2
        display "LABEL A ===> PROCEDURE NOM_PROC2 "
            "J=/"J"/ AND K=/"K"/"
    END-PERFORM
END-PERFORM
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of VARYING AFTER performs

```
   perform varying j from 1 by 1 until j > 10
       after k from 1 by 1 until k > 3
           if j = 2 and k = 2 then
               exit perform
           else
               display "j: " j ", k: " k
           end-if
   end-perform

prompt$ cobc -xj exitnest.cob
j: 01, k: 01
j: 01, k: 02
j: 01, k: 03
j: 02, k: 01
prompt$
```

COBOL 2014 (draft) spec has 14.9.27.2

```
10) At least six AFTER phrases shall be permitted in varying-phrase.
```

Comment: @MohamedELKHALIFI Well, Mohamed, on StackOverflow the thanks comes from upvotes and closing the question by picking one of the answers as accepted.  It doesn't have to be this answer, but SO users all feel better when questions gets an accepted answer. It clears out the queue and lets everyone know that things are satisfactorily resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your original code is PL/I and your remit is not to change the structure of a program if it can be avoided, then use `GO TO`.

PL/I can exit from a `DO` with a `STOP`, `RETURN` (neither of those is suitable for your situation), `LEAVE` or `GOTO`.

```
LEAVE label
```

or

```
GOTO label
```

You would change either of those to

```
GO TO label
```

And have identical results. You don't need to change the existing label even, except for a small difference in syntax, and not even have to think about any code after the label.

If you are able to change the structure of the code you already have two good answers. Brian Tiffin's is the neatest, but cschneid's will be more obvious to the majority of COBOL programmers, who will not know how to "vary" more than once on the same `PERFORM`.

Comment: That comment made me a little sad inside, Bill.  :-)  `PERFORM VARYING AFTER` is over 30 years old now.   Don't tell me that COBOL programmers are stuck in cargo cult programming; lines dug in the grass, huts with bamboo antennas, and mannequins wearing wooden headphones, in the hope that strange alien technology may drop goodies from the sky?  Say it isn't so.  If we can't drag everyone into the 3rd millennium, lets at least assume the majority can handle the mid 1980s.  No?  (another smiley).

Comment: @BrianTiffin They are fine with VARYING , they'll even use it when there is a better alternative, just to avoid having to code/think. However, `AFTER` is unknown to them. I've never seen or been asked about `AFTER`. I don't believe that that is because everyone is using it, and using it correctly.